# Boostrap style overrides custom style even though custom stylesheet included second?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I always modify Bootstrap by including my custom stylesheet after the Bootstrap one, in this particular case, like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have a list on the site, some of whose elements also have the class `advanced-only`.

The list elements have the style in Bootstrap:

```
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

And the `advanced-only` class in my custom stylesheet has:

```
.advanced-only {
    display: none;
}
```

There are other styles such as color and border but they are not relevant here. As you see, the `advanced-only` elements should be hidden when the page loads, but they are displayed. When I inspect one of these elements, I see that the `.advanced-only` style is crossed out and the `.nav li` style from Bootstrap is active. When I deactivate the Bootstrap one from there, then the custom one activates and all is well.

Also, when I do

```
.advanced-only {
    display: none !important;
}
```

it hides it like it should. However, this would interfere with a bunch of Javascript code (for example, `show()` and `hide()` won't work properly with `!important` elements) so I would like to understand why Bootstrap is overriding the custom style and what I can do about this.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li>
        <a>Pending Actions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="advanced-only">
        <a>Hidden stuff</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to be specific with your `selector` in CSS. The more specific `selector` always takes priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `specificity` of your selectors are lower than the Bootstrap selectors. Strongly suggest you reading http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity.

**The `specificity` is calculated based on many factors, not just by the order of definition.**

For example, this selector `.nav > li` has an `attribute selector` and a `tag selector`, while your rule `.advanced-only` has only an `attribute selector`. So your rule is not making affect. Try to make your selector more `specific` when giving customized styles.

Answer (score 1):

This is because bootstrap's styling is more specific than your custom styling.

To fix this you need to add a more specific selector, e.g:

```
nav .advanced-only {
    display: none;
}
```

For more reading on CSS Specifity check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).